# How to get value from Embedded Key of MongoDB using Java?

Tags: mongodb

I want to extract value of a embedded key(**detokenObject.0.client.COUNTRY**) from Mongodb document using java.
I have tried below piece of code.

```
 DBCursor cursor1 = coll1.find();
        while (cursor1.hasNext()) {
            BasicDBObject dbObject = (BasicDBObject)cursor1.next();
            BasicDBObject dbObject1= ((BasicDBObject)dbObject.get("detokenObject"));
            BasicDBObject dbObject2= ((BasicDBObject)dbObject1.get("0"));
            System.out.println("value is:::"+((BasicDBObject)dbObject2.get("client")).get("COUNTRY"));

        }
```

But after running this, getting **ClassCastException(com.mongodb.BasicDBList cannot be cast to com.mongodb.BasicDBObject)**

any solution?

Answer (score 0):

The error `ClassCastException(com.mongodb.BasicDBList cannot be cast to com.mongodb.BasicDBObject)` says it all, you are trying to cast a `BasicDBList` to `BasicDBObject` on `detokenObject` field, which is a list.

Use

```
BasicDBList dbList = (BasicDBList) dbObject.get("detokenObject");
```

instead of

```
BasicDBObject dbObject1 = ((BasicDBObject)dbObject.get("detokenObject"));
```

and then get its element `client` value by its index with `dbList.getIndex(0);`

i.e. your final code should look like:

```
DBCursor cursor1 = coll1.find();
while (cursor1.hasNext()) {
    BasicDBObject dbObject = (BasicDBObject) cursor1.next();
    BasicDBObject dbList = (BasicDBList) dbObject.get("detokenObject");
    BasicDBObject dbObject1= (BasicDBObject) dbList.getIndex(0);
    System.out.println("value is::: " + (BasicDBObject) dbObject1.get("client")
                                                                 .get("COUNTRY"));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. i will try this approach too.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried below solution to chained the keys and it worked for me.

```
public static Object getField(DBObject obj, String fieldName) {

       String[] fieldSections =fieldName.split("\\.");
       int i = 1;
       Object value = obj.getfieldSections[0]);
       while(i < fieldSections.length && value instanceof DBObject) {
           value = ((DBObject)value).get(fieldSections[i]);
           i++;
       }
       return value;
   }
```